# Defining Expected Lifetimes while implementing Traits

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implemented a "setter" like trait for a struct. See the code below:

```
struct Buffer<'a>{
    data: &'a i32
}

trait Setter {
    fn set_value(& mut self, c: & i32) -> ();
}

impl<'b> Setter for Buffer<'b> {
    fn set_value(& mut self, c: & i32) -> () {
        self.data = c;
    }
}
```

The code is pretty straightforward, the `set_value` function all it does is to set **data** equal to **c**.

When I try to compile the code, it fails to compile with "lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content", which I get why is happening. There's a difference between the lifetimes of the implementation clause and the function itself.

My question is how I can overcome this? I tried to define that the lifetime of set_value should exceed the lifetime 'b but then I start getting into issues between the signature of the trait and the actual implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lifetimes need to percolate deeper into your implementation, like this:

```rust
struct Buffer<'a>{
    data: &'a i32
}

trait Setter<'b> {
    fn set_value(&'b mut self, c: &'b i32) -> ();
}

impl<'b> Setter<'b> for Buffer<'b> {
    fn set_value(&'b mut self, c: &'b i32) -> () {
        self.data = c;
    }
}
```

Where this is saying "the lifetime of the `Buffer` will not exceed that of the `c` given".

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Is "the lifetime of the Buffer will not exceed that of the c given" expressed by setting the same lifetime for "self" and c in the set_value function? If this is the case, why do we need to repeat the lifetime definition both inside the trait and the implementation of the trait?

Comment: By saying they both have the same lifetime you're ensuring that the `Buffer` won't out-live the given `c` reference. Since the function signature has lifetimes in the implementation, the `trait` needs to include those as well so the signatures match. You can try omitting things here and see the various errors that pop up. This does seem a little verbose and heavy-handed, but Rust prefers you're exceedingly specific about how these things apply.